# How to sum up all the transactions per terminalcode

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i've written up a query in sql developer however im having few problems;
The goal is to sum up all the transactions which occured on the terminal per date

i've been playing around with the count() and still no luck , watched a few videos but still nothing i get single transaction per terminal

```
SELECT 
   count(1) AS cnt,
   p.terminalcode AS terminal,
   trunc(p.clientdate) AS payment_date,
   p.otdnum,  
   sum((nvl(p.clientsum,0)) + (nvl(p.penaltysum,0))) AS total_sum,
   nvl(p.commissionsum,0) AS upper_commission

FROM payment_cp pcp
INNER JOIN committedpayments cp
ON cp.committedpaymentid = pcp.cp
INNER JOIN payments p
ON pcp.payment_id = p.paymentid



WHERE trunc(p.clientdate) BETWEEN :p_date_from and :p_date_to                          


GROUP BY p.terminalcode, 

     cp.pay_string, 
     p.clientsum, 
     p.commissionsum, 
     p.otdnum, 
     p.clientdate
```

All i get is loads of entries for terminals and broken down to single transaction, i want to have lets say terminal x 7 transaction summed up rather than see all of the 7 transactions seperately.

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Out of the blue I would say your grouping is incorrect and your counting. If you have a unique identifier for transactions, put it into your counting like `COUNT(DISTINCT myID) AS cnt`. If you see more rows than you expect, check the attributes within the grouping. You probably group over a wrong attribute. My guess would be that you should remove 'pay_string', 'clientsum', 'commissionsum' and 'otdnum' from your grouping.

Comment: alright thanks man ill give it a try, but im pretty sure i've tried removing some of them from GROUP BY and developer didnt like it and threw out an error.